# Shared session state access between Controllers invoked via AJAX

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to provide a progress monitoring mechanism for a longish-running request implemented by an AsyncController. A web page invokes (via JQuery `$.post`) the asynchronous StartTask action on the following controller...

```
[NoAsyncTimeout]
public class TaskController: AsyncController
{
   [HttpPost]
   public void StartTaskAsync()
   {
      AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Increment();
      Session["progress"] = "in progress";
      Task.Factory.StartNew(DoIt);
   }

   public ActionResult StartTaskCompleted()
   {
      return Json(new {redirectUrl = Url.Action("TaskComplete", "First")});
   }

   private void DoIt()
   {
      try
      {
         // Long-running stuff takes place here, including updating 
         // Session["progress"].
      }
      finally
      {
         AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Decrement();
      }
   }
}
```

The same web page sets up a 2-second timer (via window.setInterval) to call the following controller (via JQuery `$.getJSON`) that has read-only access to the session...

```
[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]
public class ProgressController: Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Current()
    {
       var data = Session["progress"];
       return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

The function invoked after getJSON returns updates a DIV to show the current progress. Ultimately the progress will be updated in the session by the 'long-running stuff takes place here' code, but as it is the call to ProgressController.Current() does not find any data in the session and always returns null.

I had assumed that JQuery AJAX requests sent from the same browser to the same IIS server would end up with the same session, but it seems not. Do I need to explicitly set the ASP.NET session key on these $.post and $.getJSON calls? Or is it just not possible to share session state between Controllers (even if one has R/O access) in this way (I can fall back to a slightly hacky solution with Application state and GUIDs).

Answer (score 0):

That's normal behavior. Your `StartTask` action blocks until it completes. It doesn't return any response until the `DoIt` method has finished executing. I suppose that's why you are calling it with AJAX `$.post`. The problem is that while this method runs and writes to the session and all other requests from the same session will be queued by the ASP.NET engine. You cannot write and read from the session at the same time. You will have to find another thread-safe storage for the progress data other than the session.

Comment: Does the StartTask action really block? I thought the StartTaskAsync method returns (I think this is what I have observed in the debugger, will try again) and the ASP.NET worker thread is returned to the pool until the AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Decrement() call is received (although how ASP.NET MVC associates the thread that Decrement() is called from with the corresponding XxxCompleted() action method I'm not sure). StartTaskAsync doesn't block calls to ProgressController.Current() from the same browser instance, just that ProgressController.Current() doesn't see the same session.